# using path on tsconfig.json doesn't resolve using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

In order to avoid relative path when I import file, I try to configure angular to understand path.

So far, it's not working at all, my code :

```
//tsconfig.app.json
"compilerOptions":{
    //lot of things . If it matter moduleResultion is set to node
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
        "@modules": ["app/modules/"]
        ...
    },
}



//in a component: 
import { X } from '@modules/Y/component/index'
```

when running ng serve , the console output an error about : `: Cannot find module '@modules/Y/component/index'.`

This is definitly working with relative path like `import { X } from ../../../modules/Y/component/index`

So, I expect my tsconfig.app.json or tsconfig.json ( or maybe both) are wrong, however, I can't find any good tutorial about how to do it correctly for an angular app.

Currently using angular 4 with basic associate tools (typescript 2.3.3, angular-cli 1.0.6 and provide webpack)

Can you point out the problem to me, or give me a good doc/tuto that resolve this issue with angular please ? All the answer I have seen so far on SO or github issue didn't work at all.

NOTE  : The architecture looks like this

```
project
   |
   -tsconfig.json //had try things on this one too but does nothing.
   -src/
     |
     -tsconfig.app.json
     -app/
       |
       -modules
       -othersFolder
```

Comment: How did you set your project up? ng new normally sets things up ok and you're good to go....

Comment: I did set it up with ng-cli while angular was still on RC2.

Comment: If you're using something like VSCode, if you right click on the class in the import statement you can navigate into the source with Goto Definition. And often time editors do something like put squiggly line under the path if you've got your relative paths incorrect. I'd be checking that then.

Comment: I'd also be checking you've setup app-modules.ts correctly. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

Comment: I'm on ST. the goto is working fine, Still not working in the console so must be something else.

Comment: well , using relative path, everything is working well, so I expect my module is properly configure.

Comment: Have you tried  `"@modules/*": ["app/modules/*"]`?

Comment: @yurzui can't believe that was the problem. you are right indeed.
Just put it as an answer with a typescript link and you are done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code should work with

```
"paths": {
  "@modules/*": ["app/modules/*"]
  ...
}
```

Read more about module resolution in typescript here

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: can't give bounty until 19h.

Comment: The difference (to the first code sample in the question) is to use `/*` after the module name? ("paths" is still a child of compiler options?)